# How to view the running JAR path in cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: java, windows, powershell, cmd

1. JAR path is "D:\AA\BB\Test.jar"
2. Change CLI current path to "D:\AA\BB"
3. Execute `javaw -jar Test.jar`
4. Close CLI

In the task manager, there is only the "javaw.exe process", and the command line does not have Test.jar path information.

[image]

[image]

How to view the path of a jar through cmd, power shell commands, or other methods

Comment: Does `Get-Process | Where-Object Path -match 'java' | Format-List -Property *` show what you are seeking?

Comment: The Task Manager simply shows you the command line. It doesn't know that Test.jar is a file; it just treats it as a command-line parameter string. There is no way you can get the full path of Test.jar if you haven't provided it on the command line, other than by getting your own Java program to print it.

Comment: @lit Don't have Test.jar full path info,only javaw.exe full path

Comment: @k314159 Is there any way get Test.jar full path?

Comment: When I use the Java command `jps -l`, I still lose the Test.jar path

Comment: From the `jps` documentation it would seem that it _should_ give you the full path of the jar file, but I'm not familiar with it and don't know why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Adrian Mole reopen and amendment this question.

This is the information I currently have,
when I use microsoft official tool **Process Explorer**,I got this information

[image]

The key information is **Current directory**.
I think this is OS process concept(current working directory).

I want to do it in a simple way(like CLI)get running Jar full path,but when Jar starting in relative,I need get process CWD.

Perhaps I can simply obtain the process CWD on Linux through the CLI without coding,But I currently can't find it on Windows.

By the way,This issue is not very important,I will close it.